# excel vba showing incorrect data after certain manipulations

Tags: excel, vba

Sequence of events which I am trying to achieve:

1) I have data on Sheet1 
2) I filter the data on Sheet1 according to a certain criteria and then copy the data to another Sheet say "Difference". The data has around 8 lines. 
3) I then insert 11 lines between the data on sheet "Difference" after every 2 lines.
4) Next I insert 4 columns before the first column
5) I then insert the column header for the first 4 inserted column and row headers till the UsedRange. 
6) After that I am doing certain less intensive calculations on the data such as comparing the values and looking up data from another workbook.

All this is in a macro on click of a button.

While clicking the button what happens is that sometimes I get the rows and columns in a sequence as expected and actually most of the times after the first 4 columns the rows come in a zig zag manner i.e. sometimes they would comes 5 - 6 columns after the first 4 columns and on other runs of a macro the rows would come after 50 lines or so.

I investigated my code but couldn't find any reason why this is happening. Also this happens intermittently. As I mentioned sometimes the result comes fine and most of the times the result (rows and columns) come in a zig zag manner.

Why is macro doing this? I am really having a hard time thinking about it? I have no answer. It seems so illogical.

I could post my code but it's too big. Please let me know which portion of the code should I post.

Please do suggest. Having a really hard time.

I am posting my code snippet below:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = GetObject(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\ReconUtility_Enhanced.xlsm")

    Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set sh2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    MsgBox sh2.UsedRange.Rows.count

    For i = 1 To sh2.UsedRange.Rows.count

        sh1.Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

        Selection.AutoFilter

        sh1.Range("E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=sh2.Cells(i, 1).Value

        Selection.Copy

        With ThisWorkbook
            Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count))
            ws.Name = sh2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        End With

        Sheets(sh2.Cells(i, 2).Value).Select
        'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

    Next i

    sh1.Activate
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

    Selection.AutoFilter

    sh1.Range("E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Field Difference"

    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Field Difference").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

    MsgBox "Field Difference Copy completd"

    ' Step 2. Insert 11 lines and Insert 4 columns for analysis

    Set sh3 = wb.Sheets("Field Difference")

    Dim x As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i1 As Long
    Dim fieldRows As Long
    j = 1

    fieldRows = sh3.UsedRange.Rows.count

    Dim rowsAfterInsertingLines As Long
    rowsAfterInsertingLines = fieldRows / 2

    Const count = 11

    For i1 = 2 To fieldRows

        If i1 Mod 2 = 1 Then

            For x = 1 To count

                sh3.Rows(i1 + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                j = j + 1
            Next

        End If


    Next i1

    MsgBox "Inserted Lines Done"

    ' Inserting 4 columns before the first column

    sh3.Range("A:D").EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    sh3.Range("A1").Value = "Data Source Name"
    sh3.Range("B1").Value = "Final Status"
    sh3.Range("C1").Value = "UserName"
    sh3.Range("D1").Value = "Ownership"

    MsgBox "Columns Inserted"

    ' Now a Loop to insert the values - (CMRS, DTCC-US, Difference, 2 Eye Check, 4 Eye Check)

    Dim myModifiedArray() As Variant

    myModifiedArray = Array("CMRS", "DTCC-US", "Difference", "Sapient Comments (History)", "Last Sapient Comment / 2 Eye Analysis", "4 Eye Analysis", "4 Eye Comments", "Last Comment made by (Sapient)", "Date of Last Comment (Sapient)", "NWM Comment (History)", "Last NWM Commnent", "Last Comment made by (NWM)", "Date of Last Comment (NWM)")

    Dim rCount As Long
    rCount = 2
    Dim iCount As Long
    Dim jCount As Long

    For iCount = 1 To rowsAfterInsertingLines

        For jCount = LBound(myModifiedArray) To UBound(myModifiedArray)

            sh3.Cells(rCount, 1).Value = myModifiedArray(jCount)
            rCount = rCount + 1

        Next jCount

    Next iCount

    MsgBox "Row headers inserted"

End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's very hard to suggest which bits are relevant to post.

Comment: FWIW - I remember someone else complaining that their code was copying data in a zig-zag pattern, and I think it was simply because they had mixed rows and columns in their code.  (If I can find the question again, I will leave a link.)